# Why "Laura Morris" in Mrs. Doubtfire?

Tags: mrs-doubtfire

Toward the end of [*Mrs. Doubtfire*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs._Doubtfire), the Hillards seek a nanny and cross potential candidates off of their list:
[image: Jacqueline Shea, Kristen Ross, Erik Ross, Laura Morris, and Paula DuPré.]

[According to IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107614/fullcredits), Jacqueline Shea was a production coordinator on the film, Kristen Ross an art department coordinator, Erik Ross an office production assistant, and Paula DuPré an associate producer. Who, if anyone, was Laura Morris, or why was the name used on the list? She doesn't appear in the IMDb list of credits for the film.

Comment: Excellent question!

Answer (score 2):

On-set catering was provided by [Tomkats Hollywood Hospitality](https://www.foodandwine.com/news/tomkats-catering-tom-morales-what-hollywood-eats).

[image]

The head caterer, Tom Morales was assisted on set by his daughter and current COO **[Lauren Morales](https://www.foodandwine.com/thmb/Oy2MjDiZr4jz89T1GiFkvzK8v7Q=/750x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/TomKats-Hospitality-Bill-Murray-de73c65550b04b96b6cce65a9625a4cc.jpeg)**. It doesn't seem a leap of the imagination that the prop master confused "Lauren" with Laura and "Morales" with Morris.

Comment: And yes, this is a guess. I've reached out to the prop master to see if he can confirm this